# xDebug stability problems

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm running eclipse PDT on a xubuntu 10.9 VM, using xdebug to remote debug PHP 5.3.
I have been having a number of issues over the last 6 months, things like:

1. Debugger stops responding to breakpoints after being dormant for 20+ minutes.
2. Debugger will exit suddenly with the fatal error "unexpected termination". Requires eclipse to be restarted to debug again.
3. Non fatal errors will pop up, I possibly think this is due to modifying code during execution.

Is this an issue that can be fixed by upgrading or switching to Zen? Its *really* frustrating compared to using PyDev or Java debuggers.

Is anyone else experiencing this same sort of issue?

Comment: What version of PHP, and what version of XDebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Eclipse, xdebug is sometimes a little unstable. Here, I use Zend Studio with Zend Debugger and xdebug. Everything works fine.

About breakpoints stops, I got a issue too. The only way to control this was use the Zend Toolbar to call debugger from Firefox/IE.

I know people that works fine with Netbeans + xdebug, too.
Try to download and install Zend Debugger and configure your Eclipse to work with it. Eclipse Helios has many improvements around it - try it if you use a older Eclipse version.